# how to give node alias dynamically

Tags: path-aliases

Each time I add a content, I see a node number gets created (i.e. node/2). When I go to the node, I see in the address bar as xxx.com/node/2. Is there way node/2 can be replaced by a value of any field(i.e. title) of the node dynamically? In this case new URL will be xxx.com/nissansentra. [nissansentra is the value of the title field of that node).

I know I can go to config > url alias and give a alias name manually. Instead, I am trying to make it dynamic so I don't have to manually give a alias to each node.

Thanks.

D

Answer (score 2):

Yes there most definitely is. Checkout [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto). There are many contrib modules for this type of common functionality at Drupal.org.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto). It will let you build URL patterns for each content type based on variety of data from the [token module](https://www.drupal.org/project/token).